# StarIO printer - The required native libraries & class services are not available

Tags: java, printing, stario-sdk

I am writing a application that will need to print with a Star printer. I am trying to print a test, and all the imports and code work, but when I come to run the code, I get the following error:

```
com.starmicronics.stario.StarIOPortException: The required native libraries  & class services are not available.
    at com.starmicronics.stario.StarIOPort.getPort(StarIOPort.java:44)
    at uk.co.kiosk.aura.printer.PrinterImpl.printTest(PrinterImpl.java:60)
    at uk.co.kiosk.Main.main(Main.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

There is a jar and 2 dll's to add. I have imported the jar via File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies. Am I missing something? How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that the java jdk must be 32 bit. 64 bit jdk will not work